# How to parse an XML file with Xpath and XQuery in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, xpath, xquery

In Qt and C++ how to parse a xml file with QtXmlPatterns and QtXmlQuery ?

I have a method that receives as an input parameter an XML file and my Xpath.

```
void MyClass::readXMLFile(QString fileXml, QString xPath){
 QFile file;
 file.setFileName(fileXML);
 file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

 QXmlQuery query;
 query.bindVariable("xml", QVariant(xPath));
 query.setQuery(&file, QUrl::fromLocalFile(file.fileName()));
 QString result;
 query.evaluateTo(&result);

}
```

My method does not work properly.
Does anyone already have a method to parse an XML file with an Xpath?

In this method, 
I have errors ASSERT: "! m_baseURI.isRelative ()" in file qgenericstaticcontext.cpp line 82

Comment: Can you give us examples of the values you pass in to that method you have shown and explain and show which result you want? What does "to parse an XML file with an Xpath" mean exactly? I don't know your API but as XPath is a subset of XQuery and you seem to use an API to evaluate an XQuery I would rather expect you to pass in the string `xPath` to `setQuery` and use `setFocus` with the input file URI.

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes for fileXml I pass : C:/Desktop/file.xml and for xPath I pass : /test_xml/Colors/  My xml file is : <test_xml> <Colors> <Color1> red</Color1> <Color2>white</Color2> </Colors> </test_xml>

Comment: So you have an XPath expression `/test_xml/Colors/`? That trailing slash should give you a syntax error, independent of the XML you have.

Comment: Have you seen https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxmlpatterns-recipes-example.html from the examples section of your toolkit?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I looked at the example and in the setQuery I put :                        query.setQuery($xml, QUrl::fromLocalFile("doc($xml)/test_xml/Colors"); but it does not work. I do not understand how to use the setQuery method with the source document and the XPath ...

Comment: If you have your XQuery or XPath as a string then pass that as the first argument to `setQuery`, the second argument is supposed to be a URI you can leave empty I think. As for the input XML, how is your XPath going to refer to it, with a variable or simply as the context item or focus? If you have a simple path without a variable reference, like `/foo/bar`, then pass the input document using `setFocus`.

Comment: My xml file is local. So I get in a QString fileXml :C:/Desktop/myFile.xml                                                                                                                                                    My XPath can change as needed so I receive it in a QString xPath:/test_xml/Colors  and I put the contents of the file into a variable with bindvariable :  query.bindVariable("xml", &file); Finally I do the setQuery    query.setQuery($xml, QUrl::fromLocalFile(("doc($xml)/test_xml/Colors")); and  query.evaluateTo(&result); but it does not work...

Comment: If the XPath does not use any variable references then use `setQuery(xPath)`. For the file use `setFocus(file)`.

Comment: If I use setQuery(xPath) I have an error "The static base-uri must be absolute. This error is most likely caused by misuing the API."

Comment: same as for setFocus(file)... its strange error ...

Comment: I would try to start with something simple, according to the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html you can do e.g. `QXmlQuery query; query.setQuery("doc('index.html')/html/body/p[1]");` so for a moment forget about a variable and a particular external file and just try that basic example from the documentation. If the `setQuery` method is documented to be used that way it ought to work. You could also try something more basic to simply test use of `setQuery` with e.g. `setQuery("<test>{1 + 2}</test>")`.

Comment: I got my hands on a machine where I could install Qt-5.12.2 and then I was able to run a simple query with e.g. `query.setQuery("<test>{1 + 2}</test>");` or one reading from an input file `input.xml` with e.g. `query.setFocus(QUrl("input.xml")); query.setQuery("//foo");`. So based on that I would expect that `query.setFocus(QUrl(fileXml)); query.setQuery(xPath);` should work for you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you for your reply. I'm also on Qt-5.12.2. I will try your solution and I tell you if it worked.

Comment: Did you finally get that to work?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry for my late answer. 
I used your method with setFocus (& Myfile) setQuery (Xpath) and evalueto. It worked. Thank you so much.